# Value cannot be null.Parameter name: stream error while reading the contents of embeddded file

Tags: c#

I am doing an application in c#.

I get the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream while reading the contentxs of embedded file

in the code

```
Stream strm = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 8):

What I found is as once I faced this problem after adding a text file or template file to read the email body and than reading the path to that template file using 
below syntax:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string assemblyName = asm.GetName().Name;
string emailTemplateName = xyz.tt;
emailTemplateName = assemblyName + "." +  emailTemplateName;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(emailTemplateName)))
{
body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The file by default gets added to project library with property "Build Action"= Content. I changed value from "Content" to "Embedded Resource" and everything worked good.

Comment: Changing the build action to "Embedded Resource" on the files properties in Visual Studio fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix to embedded resources is not the *assembly* name, but rather: the *default namespace* specified on the project. Your best tactic, though, is to look at:

```
string[] names = Asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach(var name in names) Debug.WriteLine(name);
```

and see what the names *actually* are, and tweak the prefix accordingly. You will get `null` if it is not a complete match.